# Счетчик во вложенном selecte POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql

Доброго времени суток, имеется такой код,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SubmitReview() RETURNS VOID AS $$
declare 
a INT;
begin
a := 1;
while a <= (select max(id_) from test_f)
loop
insert into consumer (id_, name_, type_, abonentid_) values ((select max(id_)+1 from consumer), (select name_ from test_f where id_ = a), 
(select type_ from test_f where id_ = a), (select abonentid_ from test_f where id_ = a) );
a = a + 1;
end loop;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

т.е. таблица consumer должна заполняться полями из ТАБЛИЦЫ TEST_F, для этого есть счетчик а. цикл компилируется, но ничего не происходит

Comment: А зачем цикл ? может просто `insert into consumer (name_, type_, abonentid_) select  name_,type_,abonentid_ from test_f` только надо что бы id сами назначались нормальными средствами, max(id)+1 это очень криво.

Comment: проблема в том, что колонка id_ имеет формат bigint not null, и сделать ее форматом serial не представляется возможным, поэтому так коряво и через цикл

Comment: Есть тип данных bigserial. Хотя сейчас конвертировать уже поздно. Или можно использовать sequence.  А что до данной вставки, то можно сделать что то вроде `insert into consumer (id_,name_, type_, abonentid_)
  select maxId+row_number() over(order by id_),name_,type_,abonentid_ from test_f, (select max(id_) maxId from consumer) M`

Comment: благодарю, но я все же не понимаю чем плоха такая ручная инкрементация, когда руками к максимальному id добавляется 1, уникальность ведь сохраняется

Comment: А вы представьте, что транзакция 1 возьмет max()+1 вставит запись, но commit еще не пройдет и в это время из другого соединения транзакция 2 то же получит max()+1, но она еще не видит записи, которая была вставлена первой транзакцией, так как commit еще не прошел и следовательно получит тот же id что и первая

Comment: хорошо, а в pgsql есть возможность выставить задержку после выполнения добавления, т.е. я делаю добавление и запись недоступна в течении секунды, что то на подобии семафора

Comment: нет такого. разве что брать перед вставкой полную блокировку таблицы на чтение, что бы все остальные кто захотят получить id просто ждали. но это не хорошо. собственно serial для того и придуманы, что бы решать такие проблемы без лишних блокировок